# foreach max array value?

Tags: php, arrays, max

I'm fairly new to php and i have problem with loops. I have a foreach loop,

```
foreach ($contents as $g => $f)
{
  p($f);
}
```

which gives some arrays, depending on how many contents i have. currently i have 2,

```
Array
(
    [quantity] => 1
    [discount] => 1
    [discount_id] => 0
    [id] => 1506
    [cat_id] => 160
    [price] => 89
    [title] => კაბა
)

Array
(
    [quantity] => 1
    [discount] => 1
    [discount_id] => 0
    [id] => 1561
    [cat_id] => 160
    [price] => 79
    [title] => ზედა
)
```

my goal is to save the array which has the max price in it as a different variable. I'm kinda stuck on how to do that, i managed to find the max price with the `max()` function like so

```
foreach ($contents as $g => $f)
{

    $priceprod[] = $f['price'];
    $maxprice = max($priceprod);
   p($maxprice);
}
```

but i still dont get how i'm supposed to find out in which array is the max price. any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should store the keys as well so that you can look it up after the loop:

```
$priceprod = array();

foreach ($contents as $g => $f)
{
  // use the key $g in the $priceprod array
  $priceprod[$g] = $f['price'];
}

// get the highest price
$maxprice = max($priceprod);

// find the key of the product with the highest price
$product_key = array_search($maxprice, $priceprod);

$product_with_highest_price = $contents[$product_key];
```

Note that the results will be unreliable if there are multiple products with the same price.

Comment: just what i needed, thanks a lot. will find a solution to same prices later probably. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check max function for the array in outside the loop.

```
foreach ($contents as $g => $f)
{

    $priceprod[] = $f['price'];

}
$maxprice = max($priceprod);
p($maxprice);
```

Comment: I think I asked my question wrong, the goal is to save the array which has max price in it as a different variable for later use.

Comment: What is p() at p($maxprice)?

Answer (score 0):

Here you got single loop solution handling multiple items with same max price.

```
$maxPrice = - INF;
$keys = [];
foreach($contents as $k=>$v){
    if($v['price']>$maxPrice){
        $maxPrice = $v['price'];
        $keys = [$k];
    }else if($v['price']==$maxPrice){
        $keys[] = $k;
    }
}
```