# get max value inside foreach PHP

Tags: php, foreach, max, opencart

i've set a shipping cost for the macbook to $5 and iphone to $1.50 and add this two product in the cart. and the php code below is to get those shipping cost from the database for each product on the cart

```
$cart_product = $this->cart->getProducts();
//$query = array();
$total = 0;

foreach ($cart_product as $product) {

  $query = $this->db->query("SELECT shipping_cost FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "shipping_cost WHERE product_id='" . (int)$product['product_id'] . "'");

  if ($query->rows) {
    if ($this->config->get('calculation_rules') == 'flatrate') {
      $total += $query->row['shipping_cost'];
      $shipping_cost = $total;
    }
  } else {
     $shipping_cost = $total;
  }

}
```

the above code will return a total shipping cost of $6.50 for flatrate as it should be. but suddenly today my client want the highest shipping cost only which is $5 from macbook without sum the shipping cost of iphone

i've read something similar from this ([foreach max array value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23712864/foreach-max-array-value)) and try to achieve this outside of the foreach loop but it won't do the trick because the shipping cost is not come from the foreach loop it self. so how do get this to work?
just in case, here are my shipping_cost table structure looks like

```
product_id | shipping_cost
40         |    1.50     (iphone)
43         |    5.00     (macbook)
```

Comment: `SELECT MAX(shipping_cost) AS shipping cost ....`?

Comment: select query in `foreach` is a bad idea.Use join.

Comment: SELECT MAX(shipping_cost FROM) shipping_cost FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "shipping_cost WHERE product_id='" . (int)$product['product_id'] . "' and categrory ='macbook '"

Comment: @SergeyVidusov: i can't do this for getting max shipping cost because i had a calculation rules

Comment: @Mr.Engineer: show another way please

Comment: @SharmaVikram: the store not only have the macbook to be sell. the table structure also wont need the category column

Comment: @ZulfakarZukri Please post your tables structure and your expected output.

Comment: @Mr.Engineer: i've edit my post, please take a look. thanks

Comment: Where is your product table? This is just a shipping cost table. Right?

Comment: yes it is, the product table have a ton's of column

Comment: @ZulfakarZukri I don't know your product table's structure but this might help you :  `select sum(s.shipping_cost) as shipping_cost from shipping as s join products as p on p.id=s.product_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could tweak your code to get the max shipping rate

```
$cart_product  = $this->cart->getProducts();
$shipping_cost = 0;
$total         = 0;
$min_value     = array();

foreach ($cart_product as $product) {

  $query = $this->db->query("SELECT shipping_cost FROM "
                 . DB_PREFIX . "shipping_cost WHERE product_id='" 
                 . (int)$product['product_id'] . "'");    

  if ($query->rows) {
    if ($this->config->get('calculation_rules') == 'flatrate') {
      $min_value[] = $query->row['shipping_cost'];
      if($shipping_cost < $query->row['shipping_cost']) {
          $shipping_cost = $query->row['shipping_cost'];
      }
    }
  } else {
     $shipping_cost = $total;
  }

}
$minimum_value = min($min_value);
```

Comment: just a question, is there a way to get the min value also by using the above code?

Comment: updated the code, you could use the same array technique for calculating the max value

Answer (score 1):

You can save shipping cost to array. and get the max value from array using php max function http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php